# Always show DataTip

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

Is there any way to always show DataTip for SLider control in Flex 3.5?

Comment: Always? Then why use a datatip? Why not a label (bindable)? Or some other static control with bindable text? Perhaps I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no easy way to do it. You will probably have to extends the component and build your own datatip